# openCV triangulatePoints

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library

first at all thanks for reading.

I have an issue generating the point cloud with PCL given the info provided by openCV functions.

1. I'm using two images that the function recognized several keypoints.
2. Then i make the matches and calculate the fundemental function with RANSAC algorithm.
3. Then i printed the points in each image to see the related points and i have several points that good matched.
4. Now i'm trying to generate the point cloud to reproject those points cause the next step is making a bigger point cloud with more than two images.. to make a 3d reconstruction by 2d information.
5. My problem is that i cant fill propertly the cloud cause the points are in weird positions and all of the points seems very closer... There is something wrong with the code that i'm using?

Below functions and the matrixes that i'm using:

Calling triangulate function:

```
TriangulatePoints(keypoints1, keypoints2, K.t(), P, P1, pointCloud)
```

PopulateTheCloud

```
PopulatePCLPointCloud(pointCloud);
```

Populate Function:

```
void PopulatePCLPointCloud(const vector<Point3d>& pointcloud) //Populate point cloud
{
    cout << "Creating point cloud...";
    cloud.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<pointcloud.size(); i++)
    {
        // get the RGB color value for the point
        Vec3b rgbv(255,255, 0);
        // check for erroneous coordinates (NaN, Inf, etc.)
        if (pointcloud[i].x != pointcloud[i].x || _isnan(pointcloud[i].x) || pointcloud[i].y != pointcloud[i].y || _isnan(pointcloud[i].y) || pointcloud[i].z != pointcloud[i].z || _isnan(pointcloud[i].z) || fabsf(pointcloud[i].x) > 10.0 || fabsf(pointcloud[i].y) > 10.0 || fabsf(pointcloud[i].z) > 10.0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        pcl::PointXYZRGB pclp;
        // 3D coordinates
        pclp.x = pointcloud[i].x;
        pclp.y = pointcloud[i].y;
        pclp.z = pointcloud[i].z;
        // RGB color, needs to be represented as an integer uint32_t
        float rgb = ((uint32_t)rgbv[2] << 16 | (uint32_t)rgbv[1] << 8 | (uint32_t)rgbv[0]);
        pclp.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
        cloud->push_back(pclp);
    }
    cloud->width = (uint32_t)cloud->points.size();
    // number of points
    cloud->height = 1;
    // a list of points, one row of data
}
```

The function that fill the cloud with the 3d points (i commented the reproj_error cause  copied this code from masterinOpenCV but did not work.

```
double TriangulatePoints(const vector<KeyPoint>& pt_set1, const vector<KeyPoint>& pt_set2, const Mat&Kinv, const Matx34d& P, const Matx34d& P1, vector<Point3d>& pointcloud) {
    vector<double> reproj_error;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<min(pt_set1.size(), pt_set2.size()); i++) {    //convert to normalized homogeneous coordinates   

    Point2f kp = pt_set1[i].pt;
    Point3d u(kp.x, kp.y, 1.0);
    Mat_<double> um = Kinv * Mat_<double>(u);
    u = (Point3d)um(0, 0);

    Point2f kp1 = pt_set2[i].pt;
    Point3d u1(kp1.x, kp1.y, 1.0);
    Mat_<double> um1 = Kinv * Mat_<double>(u1);
    u1 = (Point3d)um1(0, 0);

    //triangulate
    Mat_<double> X = LinearLSTriangulation(u, P, u1, P1);

    /*Mat_<double> xPt_img = Kinv.t() * Mat(P1) * X;
    Point2f xPt_img_(xPt_img(0)/xPt_img(2),xPt_img(1)/xPt_img(2));

    //calculate reprojection error
    reproj_error.push_back(norm(xPt_img_-kp1));    //store 3D point  */

    //carga la nube de puntos
    pointcloud.push_back(Point3d(X(0), X(1), X(2)));
} //return mean reprojection error 
/*Scalar me = mean(reproj_error);
return me[0]; */

return 0;
```

}

Linear Triangulation:

```
Mat_<double> LinearLSTriangulation(Point3d u,//homogenous image point (u,v,1) 
    Matx34d P,//camera 1 matrix 
    Point3d u1,//homogenous image point in 2nd camera 
    Matx34d P1//camera 2 matrix 
    ) {
    //build A matrix 
    Matx43d A(u.x*P(2, 0) - P(0, 0), u.x*P(2, 1) - P(0, 1), u.x*P(2, 2) - P(0, 2), u.y*P(2, 0) - P(1, 0), u.y*P(2, 1) - P(1, 1), u.y*P(2, 2) - P(1, 2), u1.x*P1(2, 0) - P1(0, 0), u1.x*P1(2, 1) - P1(0, 1), u1.x*P1(2, 2) - P1(0, 2), u1.y*P1(2, 0) - P1(1, 0), u1.y*P1(2, 1) - P1(1, 1), u1.y*P1(2, 2) - P1(1, 2));
    //build B vector 
    Matx41d B(-(u.x*P(2, 3) - P(0, 3)), -(u.y*P(2, 3) - P(1, 3)), -(u1.x*P1(2, 3) - P1(0, 3)), -(u1.y*P1(2, 3) - P1(1, 3))); //solve for X 
    Mat_<double> X;
    solve(A, B, X, DECOMP_SVD);
    return X;
}
```

Matrix:

```
 Fundamental =
[-5.365548729323536e-007, 0.0003108718787914248, -0.0457266834161677;
  -0.0003258809500026533, 4.695400741230473e-006, 1.295466303565132;
  0.05008017646011816, -1.300323239531621, 1]



Calibration Matrix =
 [744.2366711500123, 0, 304.166818982576;
  0, 751.1308610972965, 225.3750058508892;
  0, 0, 1]

Essential =
 [-0.2971914249411831, 173.7833277398352, 17.99033324690517;
  -182.1736856953757, 2.649133690692166, 899.405863948026;
  -17.51073288084396, -904.8934348365967, 0.3895173270497594]

Rotation matrix =
 [-0.9243506387712034, 0.03758098759490174, -0.3796887751496749;
  0.03815782996164848, 0.9992536546828119, 0.006009460513344713;
  -0.379631237671357, 0.008933251056327281, 0.9250947629349537]

Traslation matrix =
 [-0.9818733349058273;
  0.01972152607878091;
  -0.1885094576142884]

P0 matrix =
 [1, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 1, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 1, 0]

P1 matrix =
 [-0.9243506387712034, 0.03758098759490174, -0.3796887751496749, -0.9818733349058273;
  0.03815782996164848, 0.9992536546828119, 0.006009460513344713, 0.01972152607878091;
  -0.379631237671357, 0.008933251056327281, 0.9250947629349537, -0.1885094576142884]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, i have two big problems..

First at all i was passing the non filtered keypoints to the triangulate function, so i saw the matches points and the non useful points. And probably we will have more unuseful than useful points...

So as you will see in the triangulate function i'm giving the matches points that i obtained with ransacTest and SymTest filtered. And then just using of the keypoints the index of the matches. SO everything is good =) just showing the good matchesl.

Second the triangulateFunctions was wrong.

Here its corrected:

```
  double TriangulatePoints(const vector<KeyPoint>& pt_set1, const vector<KeyPoint>& pt_set2, const Mat&Kinv, const Matx34d& P, const Matx34d& P1, vector<Point3d>& pointcloud, vector<DMatch>& matches)
{
    //Mat_<double> KP1 = Kinv.inv() *Mat(P1);
    vector<double> reproj_error;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {    //convert to normalized homogeneous coordinates   
        Point2f kp = pt_set1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt;
        Point3d u(kp.x, kp.y, 1.0);
        Mat_<double> um = Kinv * Mat_<double>(u);
        u.x = um(0);
        u.y = um(1);
        u.z = um(2);
        Point2f kp1 = pt_set2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt;
        Point3d u1(kp1.x, kp1.y, 1.0);
        Mat_<double> um1 = Kinv * Mat_<double>(u1);
        u1.x = um1(0);
        u1.y = um1(1);
        u1.z = um1(2);
        //triangulate
        Mat_<double> X = LinearLSTriangulation(u, P, u1, P1);
        pointcloud.push_back(Point3d(X(0), X(1), X(2)));
    }
    cout << "cantidad Puntos" << pointcloud.size() << endl;
    return 1;
}
```